# How to update responsible user field for test case in quality center using C#

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center

I am reading all the test cases present in the current test Set  of Test lab         .
I can able to read it however I am not able to change the responsible user for each test case 
Is there any way to do it ?

```html
foreach (TDAPIOLELib.TestSet tst in testSetList)
            {
                string nameOfTestSuit = tst.Name;
                
                TSTestFactory tstf = (TSTestFactory)tst.TSTestFactory;
                
                TDAPIOLELib.List ftest = (TDAPIOLELib.List)tstf.NewList(" ");
               
                foreach (TSTest  item in ftest)
                {
                    item["TC_TESTER_NAME"] = "AndUser"; 
                   
                    Test test = item.Test;
                    test.Name = "This is new TEst case ";
                    test.Post();
                    TestConfig tesconf = item.TestConfiguration;
                   
                    IExecutionSettings exucutionsetting = item.ExecutionSettings;
                    //tdconeection.DisconnectProject();
                    //tdconeection.Disconnect();
                    //tdconeection.Logout();
                    //tdconeection.ReleaseConnection();
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you never call the `Post()`-Method of the TSTest Object. Try calling it after changing the `TC_TESTER_NAME`-property to "post all changed values into database" (according to the API documentation): `item.Post()`.